# Override Magento Catalog Widget Link

Tags: magento-1.7, module, blocks, overrides, url-rewrite

I would like to override `Mage_Catalog_Block_Widget_Link`
I've created new module, added some code to `config.xml` but it doesn't work.
There is my code:
`config.xml`

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Module_Base>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Module_Base>
</modules>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <module_base>
            <class>Module_Base_Helper</class>
        </module_base>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <module_base>
            <class>Module_Base_Block</class>
        </module_base>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <widget_link>Module_Base_Block_Rewrite_Widget_Link</widget_link>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
    ...
 </global>
 </config>
```

My module folders structure are `Module/Base/Block/Rewrite/Widget/Link.php`
I've created `Link.php` as well

```
class Module_Base_Block_Rewrite_Widget_Link extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Widget_Link
{
  /**
   * Rewrite widget links to rid of store id in url
   *
   * @return string|false
   */
  public function getHref(){
  /* Some code inside */
  }
```

Where I did mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've found a solution as this is months old, but for others who run into this issue, this is how I resolved it.

After rewriting the block as you mentioned above, I was still seeing the original `getHref` function with it's annoying `?__store=<name>`.

After doing some digging, it seemed that the culprit was from calling the block on the CMS page using the

```
{{widget type="category/catalog_product_link"  template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml" id_path="category/<ID>"}}
```

I replaced that with

```
"{{block type="catalog/widget_link" template="catalog/category/widget/link/link_inline.phtml" id_path="category/<ID>"}}"
```

I'm relatively certain you could use widget and get the same results, but we decided to stick with block.

The second issue that arises is that with later versions of Magento, you need to make sure that the block is allowed to be displayed in the backend via **System->Permissions->Blocks** then add `catalog/widget_link`.

Once this was completed, the updated blocks showed up properly on our site.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended you to rewrite directly `category_widget_link` or `product_widget_link` blocks